# Is there an equivalent of the Ionic 2 ShowWhen component in Ionic 1?

Tags: ionic-framework

I would like to know whether there is something in Ionic 1, that does the same as the `ShowWhen` component in Ionic 2. Documentation about the `ShowWhen` component can be found [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/show-hide-when/ShowWhen/), but I can't find anything for Ionic 1.

Comment: no but this might help https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/platform-customization/platform-classes.html

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/platform-customization/dynamic-templates.html

Comment: ok i will check it out @varunaaruru

Comment: Yes that worked post as answer and i will accept it @varunaaruru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exact `showWhen` is not available in ionic1. but you can use this

[platform customisation classes](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/platform-customization/platform-classes.html) and this [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/platform-customization/dynamic-templates.html)

sample css code from docs:

```
.platform-android .bar-header {
  text-transform: uppercase;  
}
```

js sample:

```
.state('tab', {
  url: "/tab",
  abstract: true,
  controller: 'AppCtrl',
  templateUrl: function() {
    if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
        return  "templates/home-android.html";
    }
    return "templates/home.html";
  }
})
```